# Are the trees in my garden dead?

Tags: trees

We recently moved house in New Jersey and I'm finally getting around to getting the back garden into some kind of shape. There are trees along the perimeter of the property which i assume were planted for privacy. I think they are fir or pine trees. There are no no needles on the lower branches and the upper branches look pretty sparse. The bark looks very pale and is peeling.
I'm hoping someone can tell me what is wrong with these trees, and whether they can be saved or is it better to have them removed.

Thanks

Pic 1:
[image]
Pic 2:
[image]
Pic :
[image]
Pic 4:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a closeup of the needles, please? This will help in identifying the trees. Right now, I'm torn between the trees being arbor vitae or junipers, based on the bark.

Comment: Not an answer. My guess is Eastern Red Cedar (Juniperus virginiana) https://natlands.org/crows-nest-eastern-red-cedars-in-our-forest/
Better close-up photos are needed though @Chesterfield to confirm.

Comment: I've edited original question to show the needles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet money on Eastern Red Cedar, as commented. Not my choice for landscaping. And you can't grow apples because of cedar/apple rust.  And they look relatively normal for cedar( my parent lived in MO and cedars were very common. If one is planted in an open area by itself it will develop more foliage/look more healthy.